Iterating over each row for every column within a data frame
I'm working with a large data set in R in which the * character is used to denote cells with missing values. I am trying to replace cells that have this * with NA. To do this, I am trying to iterate over every row (per column) using the following code
for (i in 1:nrow(mydata)){
  if (i == "*"){
    mydata[i,] <- NA
  }
}

The code runs but the data frame remains unchanged. Can someone help me understand why it doesn't work and help with different ways to get the intended result?

You can just do this
mydata[mydata == '*'] <- NA

Generally bad form in R to loop over a data frame since it is computationally inefficient, it should only be done if a vectorized alternative is not available. Most operations on a data frame can be done without looping.
Also, your code doesn't work because you're checking whether the iterator i equals *, not if the value equals star. Your code is checking
1 == *
2 == *
3 == *
etc.

Which of course will each return FALSE, so no changes are made. To loop you'd need to loop over both rows and columns checking the value mydata[i, j] == '*' where i is your row index and j is your column index.

It looks a bit inefficient; consider using dplyr::na_if() instead. The following code should work.
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
mydata <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), na_if, y = "*"))


Where is this solution efficient?

Go with what user @Mako212 says here. It's highly recommended and the R-like way to choose.
This is just to demonstrate how you would need to modify your for-loop logic:
mydata = data.frame(
  A = c("a", "b", "*"),
  B = c("*", "b", "c"),
  C = c("*", "b", "c"))

for(i in seq(nrow(mydata)))
  for(j in seq(ncol(mydata)))
    if(mydata[i, j] == "*")
      mydata[i, j] = NA

mydata
#>      A    B    C
#> 1    a <NA> <NA>
#> 2    b    b    b
#> 3 <NA>    c    c


Yeah I just wanted to see what the loop function would look like over a data frame. Appreciate the help

I haven't used curly brackets }. They are not needed here, and often not needed.
